# How can I install Native JAI on Geoserver 2.20.x. & Geoserver 2.19.x

Tags: java, geoserver, tomcat9, jai

I'm currently setting up two Geoservers running on two separate Linux machines. One of the Geoservers is running version 2.20.2. and the other one is version 2.19.5.

I'm trying to install Native Jai and Native JAI ImageIO in order to increase the image handling performance.

Both machines are running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

> java -version 
> openjdk version "11.0.14" 2022-01-18 
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.14+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04) 
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.14+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)

So far I've followed these instructions: https://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/INSTALL.html

Specifically this part: [The instructions I followed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSABz.png)

It's still not working.

> echo $JAIHOME 
> /var/lib/JAI/jai-1_1_3/lib 
> echo $CLASSPATH 
> /var/lib/JAI/jai-1_1_3/lib/jai_core.jar:/var/lib/JAI/jai-1_1_3/lib/jai_codec.jar:/var/lib/JAI/jai-1_1_3/lib/mlibwrapper_jai.jar 
> echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
> .:/var/lib/JAI/jai-1_1_3/lib:/var/lib/JAI/jai-1_1_3/lib/jai_core.jar:/var/lib/JAI/jai-1_1_3/lib/jai_codec.jar:/var/lib/JAI/jai-1_1_3/lib/mlibwrapper_jai.jar

This is the Geoserver status page in case there is any relevant information: [Geoserver status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfrTB.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that [section](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/java.html#outdated-install-native-jai-and-imageio-extensions) still appears in the manual - it is no longer needed or recommended, but is clearly marked as **outdated**.

Comment: I saw that too. The download links in the manual are also broken.
Are you sure that it is no longer needed? I only ask because Native JAI and Native JAI ImageIO are still listed on the Geoserver status page. [Geoserver status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfrTB.png)

Comment: I've just pushed a PR to delete that section of the manual.

Comment: In that case you should probably tell them to remove it from the status page right? Since Native Jai and Native JAI ImageIO should always be false. It's pretty confusing in my opinion.

Comment: PRs are always welcome :-)